# Bundle install fails only in CircleCI(mysql2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, circleci

### Want to achieve

Thank you for browsing.
I got the following error when using "bundle install" to build with CircleCI.
In my environment, I can install the bundle without any problems.
I hope you can tell me how to solve this problem.

error

```
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

/home/circleci/myapp/web/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/mysql2-0.5.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/home/circleci/myapp/web/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/home/circleci/myapp/web/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/mysql2-0.5.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2

Exited with code exit status 5
CircleCI received exit code 5
```

### Codes

.circleci/config.yml

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  ruby: circleci/ruby@1.1.2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/ruby:2.6.5
    working_directory: ~/myapp/web
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/myapp
      - ruby/install-deps

workflows:
  version: 2
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - build
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.7'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# jQuery
gem "jquery-rails"
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 6'
gem "enum_help"
gem "config"
gem 'faraday'

gem 'acts_as_paranoid', '~> 0.6.0'

gem 'http-cookie'

gem 'kaminari'

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'devise-security'
gem 'devise-two-factor', '~> 3.1'

# AWS
gem 'aws-sdk'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

gem 'composite_primary_keys'

# Antivirus
gem 'clamav-client', require: 'clamav/client'


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

### I tried

Mention to run gem install mysql2 -v before ruby/install-deps

```
 - run:
     name: Install mysql2
     command: gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
 - ruby/install-deps
```

↓
build
↓
Another error occurred.

```
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/circleci/.rubygems/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/mysql2-0.5.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/mysql2-0.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/circleci/.rubygems/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/mysql2-0.5.2/gem_make.out

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the config.yml as follows and was able to build

```
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/myapp
      - run:
          name: default mysql client install
          command: |
            sudo apt update
            sudo apt-get install default-mysql-client
            sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
      - run:
          name: bundle Install
          command: bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```